# Set position / size of UI element as percentage of screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to use percentage positions/sizes when creating a layout. What I want is something like this...

```
^
|
|
| 68%
|
|
v
Gallery (height equivalent of 16% total screen size)
^
| 16%
v
```

I'm testing on a device which in landscape has a display of 800x480 actual pixels and I'm currently forcing it with the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
    <Gallery 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:layout_marginTop ="320px"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously I don't want to hard-code fixed `px` units but I can't use `68%` or `0.68` for `layout_marginTop` (for example). I've looked at `dp` units but I'm not sure if I can do it that way either.

I have to admit UI design is a weak point of mine so any advice would be gratefully received.

**EDIT:** For future reference if anyone is looking for a similar answer, following Alan Moore's suggestion I have the following working exactly how I want it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.68"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />
    <Gallery 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I managed to find some other examples of using `layout_weight` and decided to set the `TextView` heights to `0dp` and also used floats for the weights. Working great. :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think what you want is to set the android:layout_weight,

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

something like this (I'm just putting text views above and below as placeholders):

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="68"/>
    <Gallery 
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="16"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="16"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'll try this - I'd need to make the TextView elements transparent though as it will have a background image (sorry forgot to mention that). It should be doable though, thanks.

Comment: @AlanMoore This works for me too, but how would I do it if I wanted to define both height and weight as widths?

Comment: Hi @TheveshTheva -- if I'm understanding you correctly, you would want to set it up as a horizontal orientation, then make the layout_width more like "wrap_content".

Comment: Great answer, but notice that if you replace android:layout_weight="1" for the LinearLayout with android:weightSum="100" and set the heights of all the children to 0dp, you can remove one of the TextViews. This is because setting android:layout_weight on the LinearLayout is irrelevant in this case. If you set android:weightSum of the LinearLayout all unused weight will remain empty (just as intended).

Comment: @JacobR, great point!  I actually haven't ever used weightSum but will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: I have strange bug here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397356/set-position-by-percent-android-displaymetrics

Comment: Let's say I want a single button in the middle of the screen, 22% the size of the screen, with the center 0.3*width from the left of the screen and 0.7*width from the right of the screen. How do I do it?

Answer (score 19):

Use the  [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) or [PercentFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) from the [Percent Supoort Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?linkId=16439965#percent)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          app:layout_heightPercent="68%"/>
     <Gallery 
          android:id="@+id/gallery"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          app:layout_heightPercent="16%"/>
     <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: HOLY CRAP, That is AWESOME. Why did it take them so long to add this. Thank you! You just made my day. :)

Comment: Kind of messed up you need a custom layout to do this where it should be available in the built-in layouts...

Comment: how to add 68% and 16% in dimension file.

Comment: Both of these layouts have since been depreciated in Android API level 26.1.0

Answer (score 18):

For TextView and it's descendants (e.g., Button) you can get the display size from the WindowManager and then set the TextView height to be some fraction of it:

```
Button btn = new Button (this);
android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
btn.setHeight((int)(display.getHeight()*0.68));
```

Answer (score 9):

The above problem can also be solved using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) through Guidelines.

Below is the snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/upperGuideLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.68" />

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lowerGuideLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/upperGuideLine" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/lowerGuideLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.84" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

You can get the heigth of the screen and it's simple math to calculate 68 percent of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I'd have to do it in code rather than in the layout xml.

Comment: Not required and doable in xml using weight.