# Custom Android screen size

Tags: android, screen

I would like to know whether there is such possibility to customize the screen size on Android devices? Something like using half part of the screen and the other half is blank.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problems, you can work with percentage. There are 2 common ways:

in java:
You can get the display height from your used lcd-panel and then multiply with your number of percents. In this way, you have to format the button in your activity.

in layout xml:
You should design your layout within the xml-files and not in java code (my oppinion). Use layout-weight like following post: [set position size of ui element as percentage of screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506230/set-position-size-of-ui-element-as-percentage-of-screen-size)

Comment: I want the effect to be applied on everything including the operating system. Is it possible? Like changing the layout of the system/home/launcher?

Comment: I don't understand, why you want this. Anyway, I don't exactly know how to do that. Do you want to develop an app or is it for self use? Maybe you'll find a custom ROM on the net.