# Percentage of screen height not parent's layout height

Tags: android, android-layout

It is possible to **define layout_height in XML** as **percentage of screen height**? (not looking for percentage of parent layout via weightedSum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#general-purpose-layout-containers) which is adding two layouts that can define **width and height in percents**: [PercentFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) and [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

Here is an example of `PercentRelativeLayout`:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

> **This class was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.**
>
> consider using ConstraintLayout and associated layouts instead.

For more details see [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linearlayout you could use the layout_weight, otherwise I have not found any way to set a percentage of screen height...

Other than that the only way of setting it up is using the accompanying java file to set the it...

see [Set position / size of UI element as percentage of screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506230/set-position-size-of-ui-element-as-percentage-of-screen-size)